# Hide a button if not interacted with in a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, button, timer

I am looking to implement something similar in behavior to the zoomControl on android, where buttons appear, and stay visible if being interacted with, but if they haven't been interacted with for a certain period of time, they fade away.

General logic would be something like this:

Show Button: begin some sort of timer/event for the time I want it to display

if interaction with button occurs reset the timer/event to new time amount

if timer/event is hit, hide the button.

I could run some `performSelector` `afterDelay`, to a method that would hide the button, with every interaction, and have the hide method button called by the `performSelector` check some count/flag that would be incremented with each interaction.. and this would work, but it seems rather inelegant like:

show button : increment count :performSelector Hide after 5 seconds

button action : increment count : perform selector Hide after 5 seconds

Hide : decrement count if count !=0 do nothing, otherwise hide button

Is there a better way?  This just feels kludgy to me.

Answer (score 3):

Make an `NSTimer` with

```
myButtonHideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(hideButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then if you get an interaction before the timer fires call

```
[myButtonHideTimer invalidate];//This stops the event from triggering
```

And then recreate the timer to reset the trigger time

Comment: THank you for this suggestion.  would there be any performance considerations between this solution and Ole's?

Comment: I doubt there will be any significant performance implications considering the frequency at which you will be invalidating and recreating timers

Answer (score 0):

I would go the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` route because you don't have to handle a dedicated timer object. Don't know what you need the counter for, though.

1. Call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.
2. When user interaction occurs, call `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:`. Then call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` again.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I'm honestly having a hard time deciding between the two as to which is the better answer.  I suspect behind the scenes, both yours and Dan F's are incredibly similar in how the execute, but I am not familiar enough with the inner workings of iOS to make a fair judgement.

Comment: In fact, the action behind the scenes will be very much the same as `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` uses a timer internally.